# How to create a 3d block grid using processing language?

Tags: 3d, processing, visualization

I need to create a 3D block grid with varying height using processing language.

**Right now I am stuck at this output:**
[3D block grid with varying height(Current Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSAA6.png)

*Code for the above output:*

```java
import peasy.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.geometry.*;
import peasy.test.*;
import processing.serial.*;

PeasyCam cam;


//float i1,i2,i3;


void setup() {
  size(800, 800, P3D);
    //smooth(4);
   cam = new PeasyCam(this, 200);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(100);
  cam.setMaximumDistance(200);
}

void draw() {
    background(200);
    randomSeed(30);

    for(int x=-50;x<=50;x+=18)
    {
       for(int y=-50;y<=50;y+=18)
          {

               pushMatrix();
               translate(x,y,0);

               boxT();


               popMatrix();
          }

    }
  }

void boxT()
{
  fill( random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255)); 
  strokeWeight(4);
  translate(0,0,0);
   box(10,10,random(50));  

}
```

Now, my desired output is these 3D blocks with varying height but a **common base plane** something like this:
[3D block grid with varying heights(Desired Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaZEn.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Processing draws boxes **from the center of the box**.

If you want to draw the bottoms of the boxes at the same point, you have to translate the box half its width upwards.

Note that this line doesn't do anything:

```java
translate(0,0,0);
```

Instead, you'll want to translate the z axis by half the width of the box here.